# How to add and remove dynamic rows with "Select-Drop down", "Text Field", "Text-Area auto size" in React JS- Functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-functional-component

I am new to React JS. I need to develop the add or remove the control dynamically (rows).

> I have two "Text field" control, one "Select (Dropdown)" control, "Text Area " control, and one button (Add button) conrol in the first row.
> When I click the Add button in the second row is automatically added with first row controls. (Text field, select, text area, button). The first-row value has not changed and the second-row field is empty. How can I do this in react js functional component with React material UI with yup validation (controller-based component)?
> I got some sample code in the code sandbox. But, Code is written in-class components without yup validation and without use state. I attached the link below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/3vk7jxv69p

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    rows: [{}]
  };
  handleChange = idx => e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const rows = [...this.state.rows];
    rows[idx] = {
      [name]: value
    };
    this.setState({
      rows
    });
  };
  handleAddRow = () => {
    const item = {
      name: "",
      mobile: ""
    };
    this.setState({
      rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    });
  };
  handleRemoveRow = () => {
    this.setState({
      rows: this.state.rows.slice(0, -1)
    });
  };
  handleRemoveSpecificRow = (idx) => () => {
    const rows = [...this.state.rows]
    rows.splice(idx, 1)
    this.setState({ rows })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row clearfix">
            <div className="col-md-12 column">
              <table
                className="table table-bordered table-hover"
                id="tab_logic"
              >
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th className="text-center"> # </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> Name </th>
                    <th className="text-center"> Mobile </th>
                    <th />
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
                    <tr id="addr0" key={idx}>
                      <td>{idx}</td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="name"
                          value={this.state.rows[idx].name}
                          onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          name="mobile"
                          value={this.state.rows[idx].mobile}
                          onChange={this.handleChange(idx)}
                          className="form-control"
                        />
                      </td>
                      <td>
                        <button
                          className="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm"
                          onClick={this.handleRemoveSpecificRow(idx)}
                        >
                          Remove
                        </button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <button onClick={this.handleAddRow} className="btn btn-primary">
                Add Row
              </button>
              <button
                onClick={this.handleRemoveRow}
                className="btn btn-danger float-right"
              >
                Delete Last Row
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I expected the same output but, I want to use a functional component with yup validation (React Material UI and Controller-based component). who knows this answer let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do this in react js functional component with React material UI with yup validation

It sounds like there are a number of things you could benefit from learning more about before copy-pasting some code you find here, but I hope this helps.

### "in react js functional component"

For this, I'd recommend this quick read from [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/five-ways-to-convert-react-class-components-to-functional-components-with-react-hooks). Essentially, you need to understand that instead of state and lifecycle events being managed within the class, you will need to implement [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html). With the component you have here, this should be very easy once you've read the two links.

### "with React material UI"

This just requires changing out the HTML/CSS table with Material UI components. A simple replacement would be keeping the table structure, but using MUI form elements like their [button](https://mui.com/components/buttons/) and [text field](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/). If you are looking for a fuller and more robust update, I'd also recommend [MUI Data Grid](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/).

### "with yup validation"

This really should just require installing it in your project, and implementing it exactly [as the docs say](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup). You will just have to define the schema and check that all rows are valid via something like  `const tableIsValid = Promise.all(state.map(row => schema.isValid)).every(x => x)`, though you will want to split the results up by row rather than executing them all at once if you'd like to inform the user which row is invalid.